# How to set value as string type in <li> using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a sql table like this:

```
ID  name

aa1 Tom

bb2 Jack

cc3 Mike
```

And I use Ajax to pass these values to HTML

```
  $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (id, value) {
            $("ul").append($("<li></li>").val(value.ID).html(value.name));
       });    
    });
```

But I realized in HTML, `<li>` doesn't accept value as non-int type values. So the result I got is like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" style="width: auto" value="0">Tom</li>
<li class="list-group-item" style="width: auto" value="0">Jack</li>
<li class="list-group-item" style="width: auto" value="0">Mike</li>
```

This is the result I want jquery to tell html:

```
 <li class="list-group-item" style="width: auto" value="aa1">Tom</li>
 <li class="list-group-item" style="width: auto" value="bb2">Jack</li>
 <li class="list-group-item" style="width: auto" value="cc3">Mike</li>
```

How can I let `<li>` show the value as string type? Or is there other HTML tag that can accept string type values and also display those names in my table?

Comment: `li` tags don't have `value` attributes, those are associated with input elements. Use `text()`. If that is your desired HTML, you're going to run into many issues, I suggest a refactor.

Comment: that''s because the value in `<li>` is for `<ol>` ORDERED lists. it's not an arbitary form value, like in `<input>`. li.value lets you specify wonky numberings for ordered lists, e.g. `<ol><li value="10">... <li value="11"> ... <li value="99"></ol>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val()` in jQuery does not always equal a `value` HTML attribute.

I suggest you use `attr('value', value.ID)` instead of `val(value.ID)`.

I’d also recommend you change the `value` array to be contextual, so `user` for example, so `user.ID` and `user.name` make it easier to read – rather than having `value` littered about.

Comment: `val()` literally is the jQuery form of `value` on a DOM element. You can't force an element to accept an attribute that isn't native to it.

Comment: That’s not true Sterling – for example, a `textarea`?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards I think you're confused about the difference between the attribute and property 'value'

Comment: A textarea is considered an input element and accepts the `value` attribute. But you can't force a `li` or say a `div` to have `values` like inputs or textareas would.

Comment: But an `<li>` can have a `value` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: Yes, this one is the shortcut to achieve my goal. I was thinking to use `attr()` instead of telling`<li>` to give the text a value, but somehow I couldn't make that happen. But I moved the line of `attr()`along with the previous line of code: `$("ul").append($("<li></li>").attr('value', value.Id).html(value.name));`. That's now working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your script in order to accept `data` attributes. So you can use the function [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

So your code will be:

```
var li = $('<li></li>', {html: value.name});
$(li).data('value', yourValue);
$("ul").append(li);
```

In this way you "write" a data attribute and you can recover it later with

```
var dataAttribute = $('.myLi').data('value');
```